# How to return NumPy array from Pandas MultiIndexed Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a MultiIndexed pandas Dataframe and I would like to convert this into a numpy array where each element in the first level of the MultiIndex corresponds to a row of the matrix. So given the dataframe below :

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4 ], [2 ,1, 2, 3], [1, 3, 4 , 7], [1, 3, 5 , 7], [ 2 , 3 , 4 , 5]]),
                   columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])


df = df.set_index(['a','b']).sort_index()

df
```

[image]

I would like to return :

```
[ [ [3 , 4] , [4 , 7] , [5 , 7] ] , [ [2 , 3] , [4 , 5] ] ]
```

I have tried using  `df.unstack().values` but am having no success so far. Any tips or pointers in the right directions would be much appreciated.

Comment: Normally a dataframe `values` is a 2d array (possibly object dtype).  But with your groups that isn't possible.  Your groups have different sizes.  A list of lists is fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
[i.to_numpy().tolist() for _, i in df.groupby('a')]
```

Output:

```
[[[3, 4], [4, 7], [5, 7]], [[2, 3], [4, 5]]]
```

Use list comprehension with `groupby` level 0 or 'a' in this dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

No need of `.unstack()`, just use `df.values`:

```
print(df.values)
```

Output:

```
array([[3, 4],
       [4, 7],
       [5, 7],
       [2, 3],
       [4, 5]])
```

To get python list:

```
print(df.values.tolist())
```

Output:

```
[[3, 4], [4, 7], [5, 7], [2, 3], [4, 5]]
```

Comment: That's not quite what I am looking for unfortunately but thanks. I was hoping to get  [ [ [3 , 4] , [4 , 7] , [5 , 7] ] , [ [2 , 3] , [4 , 5] ] ]  instead of  [[3, 4], [4, 7], [5, 7], [2, 3], [4, 5]]

Comment: The sublists should be grouped by index "a"  so this answer is incorrect.